# In steps, how do I analyse the running time for a certain algorithm as big theta

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This algorithm is giving me trouble, I cannot find any sources online about dealing with the while loop that is also affected by the outer for loop. Is there a complicated process, or can you look from the loop that it is simply (outer loop = n , inner loop = %%%%) ? Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: It's linear. Bonje has the right idea for the approach, which with some corrections I added in comments gives the right answer. In general, a good method is to turn loops into sums, and plug it into wolfram alpha. Here you can see the graph of the runtime (counted as the total number of iterations of the inner loop):  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sum(log_2(n%2Fi)+for+i+%3D+1..n)+for+n+%3D+1...10000

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of the [Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) operator? If a, b, n are real numbers such that a<sup>n</sup>=b then log<sub>n</sub>b=a. The inner loop tells the computer that, multiply the number `j` by 2 a number of times (we don't know exactly what is this number, let's call it `x`) such that after this, `j` should equal to or exceed `n`.

Mathematically, this can be written as `2n > j * 2x ≥ n`

Solve for `x`: `2n/j > 2x ≥ n/j` ⇔ `log2(2n/j) > x ≥ log2(n/j)` ⇔ `log2(n/j) + 1 > x ≥ log2(n/j)`

As `j` increases from 1 to `n`, `x` decreases. From this point, I'll solve the problem in [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations), your work is to convert it to Big-Theta notation

Since `1` is constant, it can be omitted. So `x = log2(n/j)`, which is always less than `log2(n)`. So we can say the running time of the inner loop is bounded above by `O(log2n)`, which means the whole algorithm is bounded above by `O(n.log2n)`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, but this produces a loose upper bound because you approximate log_2(n/j) by log_2(n) rather than log_2(n) - log_2(j). When you do the sums using a more accurate approximation, you get O(n) rather than O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Edit:** For a better approximation and some corrections please read *Paul Hankin*'s useful comments bellow this answer. Thanks to him.

PS: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Good answer, but first, I think your i-1 should be i (currently you have a log(0) term in your sum). Second, your approximation for log(n!) is a bit loose: nlogn - (n-1)log(n-1) grows like log(n) rather than nlogn, since the terms (almost) cancel. A better approximation for log(n!) is (n-0.5)log(n) - n + c (https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/08/16/how-to-compute-log-factorial/). Then you have nlogn - log(n!) ~= nlogn - ((n-0.5)log(n)-n-c) = n + log(n) - c. So the final result is O(n).

Comment: Here you can see that the result is linear: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sum(log(n%2Fi)+for+i+%3D+1..n)+for+n+%3D+1...10000

Comment: There's a further correction -- the sums should use log_2 rather than log, which changes some constants and doesn't affect the overall complexity.